# Depth-first search in Python never returns True

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

When searching for a '3' in a tree that clearly contains a 3, the code will go into the correct "if statement", but does not return True. Why is that?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

def dfs(root, sought):

    print "root", root.value
    print "sought", sought.value

    if root.value == sought.value:
        print "inside root = sought"
        return True

    elif root.leftChild is not None and root.rightChild is not None:
        dfs(root.leftChild, sought)
        dfs(root.rightChild, sought)
        return False
```

The tree that I created with the sought value s is as follows:

```
n1 = Node()
n2 = Node()
n3 = Node()
n4 = Node()
n5 = Node()
n1.leftChild = n2
n1.rightChild = n5
n2.leftChild = n3
n2.rightChild = n4

n1.value=1
n2.value=2
n3.value=3
n4.value=4
n5.value=5

s = Node()
s.value=3
```

But the output is befuddling. I have a hunch the lack of `return True` has something to do with Python's recursive nature?

```
> dfs(n1,s)
> root 1
> sought 3
> root 2
> sought 3
> root 3
> sought 3
> inside root = sought
> root 4
> sought 3
> root 5
> sought 3
> False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the results from your recursive calls:

```
    res_a = dfs(root.leftChild, sought)
    res_b = dfs(root.rightChild, sought)
    return res_a or res_b
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Is this true for all other languages like Java as well, or only a subset including Python?

Comment: @Aspen it is true for every language. If not, unless the `root` node of the tree is equals to the `sought`, it will never return `True` (Your second condition, *always* returns `False`).

Comment: This would calculate both sides regardless if it's needed. Perhaps `return dfs(..) or dfs(...)` would be a better match.

Comment: Sylwester, you are right, but I believe that is a problem with Aspen's original algorithm. If this is a binary search tree there are even more work to be done to get the search into logarithmic time (no need to check the left subtree if you know the key is supposed to be in the right subtree).